Efficient Computation of Nested Sums
I have $\sum_{i=1}^na_i(x)\sum_{\nu=0}^Nb_\nu(x)\sum_{k=0}^\nu c_k(x)\sum_{l=0}^kd_l(x) \sum_{j=0}^l e_j(x)$ where $n=2000$ and $N=70$ and the $a_i$, $b_\nu$, $c_k$, $d_l$, $e_j$ are all functions that depend on some variable $x$ as well as all indices before it. That is, $e_j(x)=e_j(x;l,k,\nu,i)$ etc.
Is there a more efficient way to compute this sum in Mathematica without just nesting Sum's inside each other, as this has proven very slow (even when the first sum over $i$ is replaces with ParallelSum).

I suppose $\sum_i^na_i(x)$ is just a pre-factor, which need not be in the nested sum. Taking this into account, your sum requires around $n+N^4=0.024\cdot 10^{9}$ operations, which should take just a couple of milliseconds. If you cannot factor, the sum is still feasible $nN^4=48 \cdot 10^{9}$, which requires some seconds.

Is there any chance that Sum[ej[x],{j,0,l}] all by itself and without x,l,k,v,i having any values assigned might possibly give a symbolic solution that is not impossible to use? Yes it would take some time to find this, but would that plus the time to then substitute in the values for x,l,k,v,i might be less than doing all those iterations? If that works then is there any chance you might find a way to do this with the last two sums? with the last three sums? etc. I would have tested this myself before mentioning it, but we can't see any of your functions so we can know if this can work
